# Combining Another Row Based on Common Column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

From a table like this:

[image]

I need result something like this

```
Result:

color: red,blue

size:34
```

Query:

```
Declare @Attributes TABLE
(
    Varient Varchar(20),
    AllAttributes VARCHAR(MAX),
    GUID Varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Attributes
select PV.Varient_Name,PVV.Varient_Value,PA.GUID
FROM tblproductattribute PA
INNER JOIN Product_Varients PV ON PV.Id = PA.AttributeID
INNER JOIN Product_Varient_Value PVV ON PVV.Id = PA.AttributeValue
WHERE PA.GUID='2C2E23A5-AF08-4DC0-98A7-035EE6E7A06D' --and PA.AttributeID = 1

Select * from @Attributes
```

Comment: Please include an attempt of your own, rather than just saying "I need this". You might want to read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Welcome to SO, read this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey @TylerRoper Please check my query now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using STUFF and FOR XML. It would be a lot more helpful if in the future you post ddl and sample data. I did that for you this time so you can see how it should be done in the future.

And there is no letter "e" in variant. I would suggest changing that in the table or you will forever spell it incorrectly.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Variant varchar(10)
    , AllAttributes varchar(10)
    , GUID uniqueidentifier
)

declare @MyGuid uniqueidentifier = newid()

insert @Something values
('color', 'red', @MyGuid)
, ('color', 'Blue', @MyGuid)
, ('size', '34', @MyGuid)

select Variant
    , STUFF((select ',' + s2.AllAttributes
            from @Something s2
            where s2.GUID = s.GUID
                and s2.Variant = s.Variant
            for XML PATH('')), 1,1 , '') as Details
from @Something s
group by s.Variant
    , s.GUID
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution. Also, thanks for the detailed explanation of what each section does. that works pretty well
Great Thank you so much